# JNA passing String by reference to dll but non return

Tags: java, dll, reference, jna

Hi I have a problem with java and dll.

I need to pass string value to dll by reference but, It's not successful.

```
public short ReadData(int block_id, int offset, int data_size,StringByReference dataBuf, IntByReference err_code);
```

The problem is `StringByReference dataBuf`, I try many way to find solution but it doesn't work.

The call function is:

```
ReadData(0, 4, 13, ??? , status);
```

Cause it Had no .dll document.

function

```
`public static short Read_Data(int card_type, int block_id, int offset, int data_size, String dataBuf, IntByReference err_code){
        short rc;
        IntByReference status = new IntByReference(0);
         int len = data_size+16;
        //StringByReference dataBuf_ref =  new StringByReference( spaces(data_size+16));
        //StringBuilder zText = new StringBuilder ();
        //zText.append(dataBuf);
        dataBuf = spaces(data_size+16);
        //StringByReference a = new StringByReference(dataBuf);
    //  StringByReference a = new StringByReference(dataBuf);

    //Pointer ppp =  new Memory(dataBuf.length()+1);
    //ppp.setByte(len, dataBuf.getBytes()[0]);
    //PointerByReference p = new PointerByReference(ppp);


    //Pointer pp = null ;
    //pp.setString(len, dataBuf);
    //p.setValue(a.getPointer());
    StringBuffer_REF z = new StringBuffer_REF(dataBuf);

    //byte[] b = dataBuf.getBytes(); 
    //Memory m = new Memory(len+1);
    //m.write(0, b, 0, len);




    System.out.println("Read_Data");

    System.out.println("status "+status.getValue());




    rc = s_ope.ReadData(block_id, offset, data_size,?????, status); /// HERE NEED HELP
//  System.out.println("dataBuf_ref"+ a.getValue().replace(" ", "*"));

    if(rc != 0){
        System.out.println("Err Read_Data : "+rc+" - "+status.getValue());
    }
    err_code = status;
    return rc;
}`
```

Comment: Unclear: what's your question?

Answer (score 7):

I found answer to your question on [this](http://jnaexamples.blogspot.com/) site. Just create new `StringByReference` java type and it should work.

```
// This is a class that facilitates passing a String by reference to
// C library routines so that the string  may be modified by the C
// routine and the modifications is reflected on JAVA side as well
// Save this in a file StringByReference.java in current directory

import com.sun.jna.ptr.ByReference;

public class StringByReference extends ByReference {
    public StringByReference() {
        this(0);
    }

    public StringByReference(int size) {
        super(size < 4 ? 4 : size);
        getPointer().clear(size < 4 ? 4 : size);
    }

    public StringByReference(String str) {
        super(str.length() < 4 ? 4 : str.length() + 1);
        setValue(str);
    }

    private void setValue(String str) {
        getPointer().setString(0, str);
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return getPointer().getString(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to do other way. so It's end up with I need to use byte[] and use intbyreference to help convert value int in java to vb.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still needs this, just use `String[] result = new String[1]` and pass this to the native function. JNA translates result to this array and result will appear in `result[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Of the many solutions that can be found no one worked (in most cases I was getting garbage or crashing) until I found another approach that uses `Memory` class instead. My use case is a C method that return an UTF-16 string through the the parameter, with caller taking ownership:

```
SHARED_API int GetString(char16_t** str)
{
    *str = (char16_t *)malloc(sizeof(u"Hello"));
    memcpy(*str, u"Hello", sizeof(u"Hello"));
    return 0;
}
```

I then created the following class:

```
import com.sun.jna.*;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.*;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.*;

public final class StringByReference extends Memory
{
    private static boolean IsWindows;

    static
    {
        IsWindows = System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows");
    }

    public StringByReference()
    {
        super(Native.POINTER_SIZE);
    }

    @Override
    public void finalize()
    {
        // Free the pointer since caller has ownership
        Pointer pointer = getPointer(0);
        if (IsWindows)
            Ole32.INSTANCE.CoTaskMemFree(pointer);
        else
            Native.free(Pointer.nativeValue(pointer));
        super.finalize();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return getPointer(0).getWideString(0);
    }
}
```

It can be used in the following way through a `Library` object with the correct signature that accepts `StringByReference`:

```
public String getString()
{
    StringByReference str = new StringByReference();
    int rc = library.GetString(str);
    checkRc(rc, "getString");
    return str.toString();
}
```