# Java (JNA) pass-by-reference for dll

Tags: java, dll, vb6, jna

I have to translate some VB6 tool, which is used as a DLL, into another language.
Since I'm not very familiar with C++ and there are options to build a DLL from Java applications, I decided to write that in Java.

**Problem:**
In the original VB6 Code are some functions, those pass parameters by reference.
Since this DLL is used as an interface for another tool there are some calls on it's DLL, which also pass some arguments by reference.

I found a few ways to pass arguments, so they will be mutable, but all of them don't fit my problem because it would be perfect for the environment to leave the method signatures as they were.

Any idea how to solve that one without, changing the method signatures?

PS: Most byRef passed args are Strings.

Comment: Maybe a few code samples would be useful to better understand

Comment: Please clarify in your question which tools you are using to call the DLL in question
If you are talking about *receiving* parameters by reference when your tool is used as a DLL, please also specify which tools you are using to create the DLL from java, since any of the answers depend on the concrete technology and libraries that you are using for those tasks.

Comment: I am trying to create a DLL for a C# program in Java. Since I'm not that familiar with C++ and saw, that it's possible to do some native things via the JNI or JNA, I decided to do that in Java. JNA is pretty good for calling functions of other DLLs and wrapping all that into a DLL. The only problem I have, are reference parameters. I've been not able so far to pass an argument from C# to a Java Method in the lib and change it's value within. Thats the only problem for me that Java has natively. Still looking for a work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this library here (JNA), this should allow you to do what you want.

https://github.com/java-native-access/jna

Though calling DLLs from Java is not a great choice, it would have been easier to use C# for that task.

Comment: I'm already using this one for calling external DLLs. Thanks for the tip, haven't seen, that it's also having so much for references.
Are you a little familiar with this library?
I found a good example for a StringByReference class [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29162569/jna-passing-string-by-reference-to-dll-but-non-return), but I'm still not sure, if I can just declare a parameter as a StringByReference or even a Pointer, if it's a String passed by reference

Comment: Sorry, our project eventually had decided to wrap the DLLs we needed this for in C# statically instead (because it is very easy to do), and to export the functions as a webservice (long story), so I only know that it is *possible* with jna, but my working examples have been gone for around 5 years now ^^